# Kotlin most efficient way sequence to set

Tags: kotlin, sequence

Hi I've got list of 1330 objects and would like to apply method and obtain set as result.

```
        val result = listOf1330
            .asSequence()
            .map {
                someMethod(it)
            }
        val resultSet = result.toSet()
```

It works fine without toSet but if then execution time is about 10 times longer. 
I've used sequence to make it work faster and it is but as a result I need list without duplicates (set).

**Simply: What is most effective way to convert sequence to set?**

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. It can't possibly work fine without toSet(): the code wouldn't compile. Clarify your question.

Comment: Answer: the most efficient way is to call toSet() on the sequence. How could anything else be more efficient?

Comment: why wouldn't it work, @JBNizet? In Kotlin you don't need to specify the toList(), toSet() variants as in Java.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi because Sequence.map() returns a Sequence, not a Set. And Sequence doesn't implement the Set interface. So you can't initialize a variable of type Set with a Sequence.

Comment: Yes, but the OP said he has used "Sequence" to make it work. I assume he said it would work without `toSet()` given the code was `listOf1330.map{ someMethod(it) }`

Comment: If I would like to create any collection from sequence it takes a lot of time. It's just curiosity why it works so slow. Ok lets say that there is no type declaration (: Set<someObject>)

Comment: This requirement doesn't make much sense. A Set is a very different collection from a List. They're not interchangeable. They have different features and don't work the same way. If you need a Set, create a Set. If you need a List, create a List. If you need another kind of collection, create another kind of collection. We can't explain why some code is slow if we don't know what you mean by slow (it's relative), and what the code looks like. My guess is simply that your method  someMethod() is what makes it slow.

Comment: If you're comparing the time to create a Set that way to the time it takes to simply create the sequence without transformaing it to any collection, of course it's slower: a Sequence is lazy. it doesn't do anything until you execute a final operation like toSet().

Comment: Ok so I've made now what you can see. Move toSet to another line and I'm sure that its working slow. I mean: result is created in 8000ms when resultSet is 90000ms

Comment: As I just said: creating the sequence doesn't do anything. It's instantaneous. What takes time is iterating through every element of the sequence, mapping it by calling someMethod() on each of them, creating a Set, and populating it. That all happens when calling `toSet()`. So what is slow is most probably your method someMehod() (or your hashCode() method, but that's unlikely)

Answer (score 7):

```
 val result = listOf1330.mapTo(HashSet()) { someMethod(it) }
```

It makes less sense to use streams or sequences to implement the transformation - you will need all elements from the collection, not several. The `mapTo` (and `map`) functions are `inline` in Kotlin. It means the code will be substituted into the call site, it will not have lambda created and executed many times. We use `mapTo` to avoid the second copy of the collection done by the `toSet()` function.

The `.parallelStream()` may add more performance, if you like to run the computation in several threads. It is still a good idea to measure how good the load is balanced between threads. The performance may depend on the collection implementation class, on which you call it

Answer (score 1):

If your `someObject` has a slow implementation of `equals()` or `hashCode()`, or gives the same hash code for many objects, then that could account for the delay, and you may be able to improve it.

Otherwise, if the objects are big, the delay may be mostly due to the amount of memory that must be accessed to store them all; if so, that's the price you'll have to pay if you want a set with all those objects in memory.

`Sequence.toSet()` uses a `LinkedHashSet`.  You could try providing another `Set` instance, using e.g. `toCollection(HashSet())`, to see if that's any faster.  (You wouldn't get the same iteration order, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `gidds` answer on `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` performance.

> LinkedHashSet is more expensive for insertions than HashSet;

However, in the above use case, I think we can leverage `parallelStream` to improve the performance. Under the hood, Kotlin uses the Java parallelStream.

```
val result: Set<String> = listOf("sdgds", "fdgdfsg", "dsfgsdfg")
            .parallelStream()
            .map {
                someMethod(it)
            }.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

The `Collectors.toSet()` uses `HashSet`. So, we should be ok in insertion performance perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distict` or `distictBy`.

```
val result = sequenceOf("a", "b", "a", "c").distinct()
 // -> "a", "b", "c"

// for more complex cases use custom comparator function
val result = getMyObjectsSequence().distinctBy { it.name }
```

This approach lets keep using sequence without involving explicit Iterables (List, Set, etc.).
Nevertheless, there is no magic, and "distinct" still uses HashSet under the hood and in case of really huge sequence it may cause sufficient memory usage and it must be kept in mind while applying this function.